# Kubuntu clock widget

Tags: kubuntu, kde

Kubuntu plasma desktop shows wrong time in its time widget although the real time and timezone are set correctly. This issue appeared here some time ago but it looks like it is back in a new version of Ubuntu. Previous solutions found here or anywhere else are invalid or not-applicable because of differences between systems, basically the files/system options used are invalid or no longer exist. So here is the output of `timedatectl`:

```
$ timedatectl status
                      Local time: Mon 2018-11-05 13:26:40 GMT
                  Universal time: Mon 2018-11-05 13:26:40 UTC
                        RTC time: Mon 2018-11-05 13:26:40
                       Time zone: Europe/Dublin (GMT, +0000)
       System clock synchronized: yes
systemd-timesyncd.service active: yes
                 RTC in local TZ: no
```

It shows that RTC is not in local time but it is, believe me.

Similarly my time and zone are everywhere the same as above yet the toolbar clock is 2 hours back. I tried to reset and apply various solutions found on the internet but in vain, nothing changes.

I believe the widget time is based on `/etc/localtime` file (why it cannot be based on system time ??? ) but my file is not readable, I have no idea what's inside.

The best would be fixing this but I also accept the way of getting rid of the clock widget from my toolbar (I couldn't find the way), I don't the clock which shows bullshit time.

This screenshot shows the issue a bit better, basically there is nothing to adjust as the time seems to correct but widget shows it wrong.

[image: screenshot of Date & Time — System Settings Module]

The only applicable solution was to delete localtime file from `/etc` and reset time and zone again. It change the time displayed to 1 hour back, not 2, it is still incorrect.

Comment: Not an expert at this, but I believe the time widget is based on some local **user** setting (a Unix system could have several users in various timezones). What says Systems Settings>Personnalization>Regional settings>Date & time?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more investigations I found that the localization files are screwed, my local time is Europe/Dublin which is and always been the same as Europe/London.
I changed my timezone for London and the time is back to normal.
It looks like dublin file in /usr/share/zoneinfo/ is wrong, pointing to wrong time or so ???